# Delete a Line from BIG CSV file Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have an 11GB CSV file which has some corrupt lines I have to delete,  I have identified the corrupted lines numbers from an ETL interface.

My program runs with small datasets, however, when I want to run on the main file I'm getting MemoryError. Below the code I'm using Do you have any suggestion to make it work?

```
row_to_delete = 101068
filename = "EKBE_0_20180907_065907 - Copy.csv"
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8' ,errors='ignore') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    print(data[row_to_delete -1 ])
    data [row_to_delete -1] = ''
with open(filename, 'wb',encoding="utf8",errors='ignore') as file:
    file.writelines( data )
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.PyCharmCE2018.2/config/scratches/scratch_7.py", line 7, in <module>
    data = file.readlines()
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than read the whole list into memory, *loop over the input file*, and write all lines *except* the line you need to delete to the a new file. Use `enumerate()` to keep a counter if you need to delete by index:

```
row_to_delete = 101068
filename = "EKBE_0_20180907_065907 - Copy.csv"
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as inputfile,\
     open(filename + '.fixed', 'wb', encoding="utf8") as outputfile:
    for index, line in enumerate(inputfile):
        if index == row_to_delete:
            continue  # don't write the line that matches
        outputfile.writeline(line)
```

Rather than use an index, you could even detect a bad line directly in code this way.

Note that this writes to a new file, with the same name but with `.fixed` added.

You can move that file back to replace the old file if you want to, with [`os.rename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename), once you are done copying all but the bad line:

```
os.rename(filename + '.fixed', filename)
```

Comment: @Martinj `Rather than use an index, you could even detect a bad line directly in code this way.` how to delete lines throw codec error from huge csv?

Comment: @SIslam: decoders work on whole blocks of bytes, not on lines. You'd either have to write your own decoder to detect and handle issues on a per-line basis or do what this answer does and switch error handlers. The question asker used `ignore`, so my answer does too, but there are [other error handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers) to choose from. You could use `replace` and look for lines with `\uFFFD` in them, for example.